# Criar componente para ser usado via npm

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack

Comecei a trabalhar muito com `vue` e passei a utiliza-lo em todos os projetos na empresa em que trabalho. E com isso, acabei criando alguns `componentes`, em geral `autocomplete`, sei que existem muitos, já cheguei a utilizar alguns, mas nenhum supriu todas as minhas necessidades. Porem, sempre que vou trabalhar em um novo projeto e utilizar o mesmo componente, ou eu recrio ele, ou eu copio e colo.

Então me veio a duvida **Como criar o meu componente, subir para o npmjs** para sempre que eu for utiliza-lo, apenas dar um `npm install -save ...`, e tambem poder contribuir um pouco com a comunidade.

Answer (score 5):

Você deverá versionar todos os seus componentes separadamente e indicar qual é o arquivo de índice (no caso o arquivo do componente) no package.json.

**Exemplo de componente de input de formulário usando o webpack**

- Primeiro, crie uma pasta e dê um `git init` nela.
- Dentro dela crie o arquivo do componente, no caso desse exemplo o `AppFormInput.vue` contendo toda a estrutura, lógica e estilo do componente.
- Agora, crie um package.json (pode ser o padrão do npm init) porém você deve indicar qual é o arquivo "main", do mesmo modo abaixo:

  ```
  "name": "app-form-input",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "AppFormInput.vue",
  "author": {

      "name" : "Dian Carlos"

  }
  ```

Após isso dê os commits e siga os passos padrões para subir um projeto no npm, que você encontra em https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

Com o componente publicado, você será capaz de instalar ele com `npm i --save app-form-input`.

**Exemplo de uso do componente dentro de um arquivo .vue**

```
<template>

    <div class="form">

        <app-form-input name="titulo"></app-form-input>

    </div>

</template>

<script>

import AppFormInput from 'app-form-input';

export default {

    components : {

        AppFormInput

    }

}

</script>

<style lang="css">

    .form {

        float: left;

        width: 100%;

    }

</style>
```